# When I add an opacity < 1 to parent, the backdrop-filter: blur(20px); property seems to stop working

Tags: html, css

When I add an opacity  < 1 to parent, the backdrop-filter: blur(20px); property seems to stop working.

```
.parent-div {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.5;
   
    .child{
        display: flex;
        background: rgb(218 218 218 / 35%);
        backdrop-filter: blur(20px); <-- this stops working when parent element has opacity < 1
    }
}
```

Applying opacity to children doesn´t seem to fix the problem.

Comment: Please add the browser and precise version of it where you reproduce this issue. May be related to the fact that opacity creates a new rendering stack in some browsers.